# Is the definition of $\textbf{BPP}$ robust for doubly exponential small (or even smaller) error?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, probabilistic-algorithms

$\textbf{BPP}$ is usually defined in terms of probabilistic polynomial-time TMs which have an error probability of at most $\frac{1}{3}$. Furthermore, using the Chernoff bound it can be proven that the definition of $\textbf{BPP}$ is robust (i.e., the class remains the same) if we require the error probability to be upper-bounded by $\varepsilon(n) = \frac{1}{2^{p(n)}}$, where $p$ is a polynomial and $n$ denotes the input length.

Do we know what happens if we require (asymptotically speaking) smaller and smaller error probabilities? In particular, do we know whether $\textbf{BPP}$ is robust if we choose the error probability to be, say, upper-bounded by $\varepsilon(n) = \frac{1}{2^{2^n}}$?

I thought this could be shown using (again) the Chernoff bound
$$\text{P}(|\bar{X} - \mu| \ge \varepsilon) \le e^{-2\varepsilon^2 m}$$
(where $\bar{X}$ is the mean value of $m$ independent samples, $\mu$ is the expectation (i.e., the PPT's error probability), and $\varepsilon \in (0, \mu]$), but I don't see a way to do so except taking $m = 2^n$ exponentially many samples.

Comment: Since a BPP algorithm runs in polynomial time, if its error probability is $1/2^{n^{\omega(1)}}$, then it actually makes no error at all.